# How enable scroll using scroll composite in gridlayout?

Tags: java, layout, swt

Below code is working fine if i am using shell. but i am using the composite its not working.

code working fine if we use the shell:

```
   Display display = new Display ();
    Shell shell = new Shell (display);
    shell.setLayout(new GridLayout());  
    final ScrolledComposite sc = new ScrolledComposite(shell, SWT.BORDER | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL);
    sc.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true, 1, 1));
    Composite c = new Composite(sc, SWT.NONE);
    c.setLayout(new GridLayout(10, true));
    for (int i = 0 ; i < 300; i++) {
        Button b = new Button(c, SWT.PUSH);
        b.setText("Button "+i);
    }
    sc.setContent(c);
    sc.setExpandHorizontal(true);
    sc.setExpandVertical(true);
    sc.setMinSize(c.computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT));
    sc.setShowFocusedControl(true);
    shell.setSize(300, 500);
    shell.open ();
    while (!shell.isDisposed ()) {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch ()) display.sleep ();
    }
    display.dispose ();
```

same code is not working if we use the composite in gridlayout:

```
   Display display = new Display ();
    Shell shell = new Shell (display);
    shell.setLayout(new GridLayout());
    Composite c1 = new Composite(shell, SWT.NONE);
    c1.setLayout(new GridLayout());
    final ScrolledComposite sc = new ScrolledComposite(c1, SWT.BORDER | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL);       
    sc.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true, 1, 1));
    Composite c = new Composite(sc, SWT.NONE);
    c.setLayout(new GridLayout(10, true));
    for (int i = 0 ; i < 300; i++) {
        Button b = new Button(c, SWT.PUSH);
        b.setText("Button "+i);
    }
    sc.setContent(c);
    sc.setExpandHorizontal(true);
    sc.setExpandVertical(true);
    sc.setMinSize(c.computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT));
    sc.setShowFocusedControl(true);
    shell.setSize(300, 500);
    shell.open ();
    while (!shell.isDisposed ()) {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch ()) display.sleep ();
    }
    display.dispose ();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your aren't telling your `c1` composite how it should behave in relation to its parent (i.e. set a layout data).

You have two options:

```
c1.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));
```

**OR**

```
shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());
```